# Two different closeEvent pyside

Tags: pyside

I would like to know if it's possible to have two different closeEvent. I'm trying to make a setup program in Pyside but I'm looking for a closeEvent with MessageBox if the user want to close the windows during the installation and one a the end of the installation, just to quit the setup program without MessageBox this time.

I'm not sure that's possible in Pyside and I really need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `closeEvent` doesn't know anything the current state of the installation, so you will have to tell it yourself. A simple flag would seem adequate:

```
        def closeEvent(self, event):
            if self._installation_complete:
                # close normally
                event.accept()
            else:
                # show message
                event.ignore()
```

Now all you need to do is set `self._installation_complete = True` at the appropriate moment.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I'm a newbie in Pyside and I don't think and use flag. Thanks for your help !!